# How to run application continously?

Tags: android, flutter

How to run application task continously? I have tried create foreground service, but android kill it after X hours (max 1 day). So is there some alternative to service, which android won't kill? I'm using API highter than 26.

Comment: Related: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: @MorrisonChang and what I should do when it says "No known solution on dev end" ? :)